# Help me to choose b/w flash and html5

Tags: flash, html

I am planning to develop a facebook application which uses iframe concept, it involves some rich UI and image manipulation, I am new to html5 but aware of flex, so please help me in deciding which technology is best suitable for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particularly if its for a facebook application, I prefer you to go for flash, because html5 is not widely adopted by all users yet, you already know flash, flash has only drawback on ios platform which is not a case for you.

Answer (score 0):

if it hurries, you should choose flex. else you first should figure out if e.g. this image manipulation is even possible with canvas. And if it is clearly possible: keep in mind, that not every web browser supports html5! IE6 is still out there..

no flash on iphones isnt a point here, because iphone users use the facebook app, which doesnt allow access to any apps.

maybe theres a chance to do it with javascript?